# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' | Django

Tags: python, django, error-handling

I'm using **Django** to build an **ecommerce webapp**. I wrote this code in **models.py**

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.AutoField
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    subcategory = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='mainShop/images', default="")
```

Then, I performed **makemigrations** using

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

which produced the following

```
D:\Projects\PyCharm Projects\VeroniCart\home>python manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected
```

Then I did

```
python manage.py migrate
```

This gave me the error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I'm also attaching a [log file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DIhncm4qmS1pZX6LMyfnnw4tPHsVksdH) with the complete error.
Any help appreciated!

Comment: Post the code of the migration 0003_product_price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue solved**. All I did was I **deleted all files** from my app's **migrations directory** (except migrations/init.py) and **deleted** the database file **db.sqlite3** from the project directory.
Then I repeated the previous steps (makemigrations and migrate).

Django again created all **migrations** files and a new **db.sqlite3** file, so this worked for me.